# Uso obrigatório do MCVE?

Tags: debate, suporte

Existem casos onde tenho um código complexo, muitos arquivos envolvem. No caso [deste post aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255957/borda-arredondada-nos-bot%C3%B5es-do-google-chrome-ios), é um problema que foi resolvido com uma especulação, porém não achei necessário perder um tempo grande mudando nome de `class` e `id` no meu arquivo `css` nem mudar nomes de variável e métodos do código da empresa onde trabalho, por **questão de segurança 
 e sigilo também**.

É necessário sempre colocar o MCVE, mesmo quando uma pergunta foi solucionada com uma especulação? Não deveria ter uma atualização dizendo os casos onde não é necessário (obrigatório) colocar o MCVE?

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou sua postagem no meta

Comment: Se sua pergunta for algo teórico ou a respeito de um termo ou até mesmo em relação a alguma característica particular da linguagem não é necessário um mcve (podem haver exceções), mas precisa contextualizar bem e ter objetividade. E caso contrário, procure sempre criar o mcve porque vai facilitar uma resposta mais precisa. E além de ajudar você, ajuda outras pessoas também.

Comment: Não entendi a tag de novo recurso, que recurso você gostaria?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meu comentário ali é uma dica pro futuro, pois se ficar na especulação volta e meia vai gerar perguntas dentro de pergunta, ali foi meio que sorte o rapaz ter acertado de primeira, isso porque ele tem um *Mac OSX* e pode testar, ainda sim poderia ter outros problemas que só ocorreria no seu CSS, então resumindo:

- MCVE não é obrigatório
- As dicas lá são para evitar problemas em perguntas futuras
- Especulação ou chutar possibilidades as vezes dá certo, mas pode dar muitos problemas
- Ainda sim MCVE é altamente recomendado para evitar todos e quaisquer possíveis problemas de entendimento

Comment: Eu acho engraçado.....o Chrome foi atualizado semana passada e eu tive o mesmo problema. No inspect aparece o CSS padrão do browser, na versão antiga nao tem border-radius, na nova tem. Isso não é especular ou chutar uma informação. O usuário reportou que apareceu uma borda arredondada que nao estava no CSS dele. Como falei no próprio post, um arquivo html vazio com um button já simula o problema. Pra mim isso tudo é pura implicancia. O autor do post disse que corrigiu, o problema era esse mesmo e não foi uma especulação minha. Foi comprovação que tive, pois tive o mesmo erro no meu ambiente.

Comment: MCVE de qualquer coisa q ele postar nao vai adiantar de nada pra esta questão. O problema é do browser e nao do código.

Comment: @KarlZillner mais uma vez, não estamos falando da atualização do browser, estamos falando a "possibilidade" de haver mais problemas além disto. Ninguem tá falando que sua resposta tá errada, leia a questão do META inteiro e as respostas, o motivo aqui é "como atuar no site para evitar problemas", isso é um problema na pergunta e não na sua resposta.

Comment: @KarlZillner e por favor, leia o link do MCVE, MCVE não é uma tecnologia, é uma "dica" de como atuar no site para evitar dificuldades que possam ocorrer para quem vá responder: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve --- **Não** fui eu quem inventou a sigla MCVE, nem fui eu quem criou este link, esse link pertence ao pt.stackoverflow.com e são dicas úteis.

Comment: 1 o problema não era de código, 2 vc mesmo diz aqui que MCVE não é obrigatório, 3 o problema foi solucionado mesmo sem MCVE, 4 se a gente quiser fazer agora um MCVE para deixar a pergunta mais completa, ainda assim não teríamos como fazer um MCVE de um problema que é do browser......ou seja......não restava fazer mais nada no post além de reclamar.....vc optou por reclamar. Ok...vamos ficar debatendo então como fazer algo que não é possível fazer pra solucionar um post solucionado.

Comment: @KarlZillner oh my ... pare de levar pro outro lado e como um ataque pessoal, eu já disse que não é isso, não tem haver com sua resposta, ela esta correta. Não sei pra que esse carnaval todo, eu já expliquei, o proprio autor da pergunta entendeu, só você que fica levando pro lado errado da coisa. Preste atenção, você viu o CSS do autor? Não. Existiria a possibildade antes do autor confirmar (com o sinal verde) que sua resposta estava correta de haver outras novidades nas mudanças do Chrome que seriam conflitos de css-rules? Sim. Então é esse o ponto, tá explicado já:

Comment: MCVE é altamente recomendado e como disse o Maniero: Fazer um MCVE é um sinal de respeito a quem pode lhe ajudar.... Ou seja ali não foi necessário porque felizmente você acertou na base do chute, otimo, esta resolvido, mas poderia não ter resolvido, poderia ser outra coisa. A dica para o autor da pergunta é para futuras perguntas, então por favor pare de levar pro lado pessoal, entenda que MCVE é o ideial para futuras perguntas e todo mundo já entendeu e espero que você entenda também. Até outra hora.

Answer (score 8):

Pra mim o MCVE não é obrigatório, mas é como se fosse. Pelo menos nos casos que o problema está em um código.

**Fazer um MCVE é um sinal de respeito a quem pode lhe ajudar**. Você precisa de ajuda, então ajude as pessoas te ajudarem. Mostra comprometimento, mostra que vale a pena ajudar você.

Isto não só facilita a vida de quem for responder e ajudar mais quem for consultar aquilo depois, mas ajuda o autor da pergunta achar a solução do problema sozinho, ou pelo menos se aproximar disto. Mais ainda, ajuda ele a programar melhor, achar erros de forma melhor, se virar sozinho, evoluir, ter condições de ganhar mais por que é melhor. É um ganha-ganha.

Pedir um MCVE é a melhor coisa que um programador pode fazer por outro que ainda não se convenceu da sua utilidade. As pessoas deveriam fazer MCVE o tempo todo em seus códigos. Muitos problemas não existiriam só por causa disto.

Curiosamente as pessoas falam tanto em programar orientado a objeto e não querem fazer um MCVE, não existe OOP sem MCVE.

Comment: `Fazer um MCVE é um sinal de respeito a quem pode lhe ajudar. ` - isso deveria ser fixado no texto da pagina de ajuda do mcve no site.

Comment: É verdade, embora eu acho que seria mais eficiente mostrar para a pessoa que é um beneficio para ela mesma. Ainda que para quem acha que não é importante não sei se muda muito, porque em geral é teimosia.

Comment: *não existe OOP sem MCVE* +1 :D

Answer (score 5):

MCVE (***M***inimal, **C**omplete and **V**erifiable **E**xample) não tem nada a ver com segurança ou sigilo. No seu caso, bastaria criar uma página de "*Hello World*" com alguns botões escritos "*Bom dia*", "*Boa tarde*" e "*Boa noite*" ou algo semelhante que reproduzisse o problema e então, além de postar o código, postar uma imagem com o resultado obtido e uma com o resultado esperado. Não existe nenhuma violação de sigilo ou de segurança nisso.

Ocorre que esse monte de `id`, `class` e métodos do lugar onde você trabalha nada tinham a ver com o problema. Ou seja, se você os incluísse na sua pergunta, não seria um MVCE porque você estaria falhando na parte do **M**.

O MVCE não é apenas um método de se postar perguntas no StackOverflow. Ele também é um poderoso método de debug. Crie uma nova base de código a partir do seu original e vá retirando dela tudo o que for possível que não tenha relação com o bug até restar apenas um programa cuja a única finalidade seja demonstrar o bug e mais nada (ou seja, mínimo). Obviamente, esse programa em momento nenhum pode deixar de ser executável (completo) e reproduzível por outras pessoas (verificável).

Quando você já tiver alcançado um problema mínimo, trocar `id`s e `class`es restantes deverá ser trivial, se é que alguma restará.

Ao realizar o processo de se se reduzir um sistema complexo a um MVCE, é muito provável que você acabe achando a resposta por si mesmo, talvez não no seu caso específico, mas em muitos outros é o que acontece. E isso evita que muitas perguntas sejam postadas por aqui (obviamente, não dá para se saber quantas).

Aliás, o MVCE tem a ver com o método científico utilizado em várias áreas da ciência. Para entender a causa de um fenômeno, é necessário isolá-lo, separando-o de quaisquer outros fatores que possam interferir ou confundir o fenômeno a ser observado. Grande parte das pesquisas nas áreas de bioquímica e de física por exemplo, são realizadas assim. A descoberta do vírus do mosaico do tabaco foi realizada a partir da observação de Adolf Mayer que percebeu em 1886 que plantas de tabaco doentes podiam infectar plantas sadias a partir do contato físico. Para isolar-se o agente infeccioso, folhas doentes foram separadas e submetidas a diversos processos de filtragem e separação dos componentes, processo esse que foi replicado por vários cientistas. Em 1892 já se sabia que o agente infeccioso era algo pequeno demais para ser uma bactéria, mas ainda não havia sido isolado. Em 1898, foi demonstrado que esse agente infeccioso se multiplicava e se acumulava dentro das células da planta, e uma vez que claramente não era uma bactéria, foi então batizado de vírus. O isolamento só ocorreu em 1935 por Wendell Meredith Stanley, que isolou o vírus em uma forma cristalizada, capaz de infectar plantas sadias. Com isso, Stanley tornou-se um dos ganhadores do prêmio Nobel de química de 1946.

O processo de isolamento do vírus do mosaico do tabaco a partir da observação de que plantas doentes infectavam plantas sadias demorou 49 anos. Entretanto, felizmente isolar-se bugs em softwares é uma tarefa bem mais simples, mais rápida e menos trabalhosa do que isolar-se vírus em plantas. Além disso, naquela época não havia StackOverflow e nem Google. Assim sendo, realizar-se um MVCE para isolar-se um problema referente a botões com cantos arredondados não deve levar mais que algumas poucas horas no máximo, provavelmente alguns minutos apenas.

Há duas técnicas para produzir-se o MCVE, uma aditiva e uma subtrativa. A subtrativa é aquela onde partindo-se de um sistema grande onde o fenômeno é observado, partes do sistema vão sendo retiradas e simplificadas até que se chegue em um sistema mínimo onde o bug esteja isolado. Entretanto, a técnica aditiva também é possível (especialmente no seu caso), onde partes do sistema maior que manifestam o problema são adicionadas até que o bug surja. Frequentemente, uma combinação de aspectos aditivos e subtrativos faz-se necessária, embora a maior ênfase esteja no subtrativo mesmo.

Criar-se um MCVE perfeito pode até ser uma tarefa difícil, mas, embora o **M** seja o aspecto mais apreciável do MCVE, são o **C** e o **V** os mais importantes, pois são eles que permitem que outras pessoas possam analisar, replicar e portanto pesquisar o problema. Logo, você não precisa fazer um esforço hercúleo para ter certeza de que chegou no mínimo do mínimo e que não existe mais uma única vírgula que possa ser reduzida ou simplificada. Você só tem que se esforçar o suficiente para tirar as partes que claramente e obviamente nada têm a ver com o problema (incluindo informações sigilosas), pois os aspectos mais importantes são o fato de ser **C**ompleto e **V**erificável.

Um outro aspecto importante é que testes de unidade também são uma aplicação do MCVE. Em cada teste de unidade desenvolvido de forma adequada, você testa uma parte mínima e isolada do software, realizando sobre ela um exercício que deve produzir um resultado esperado. Se o teste falhar, ele já vai te dizer qual é o componente que está com problema, sob quais circunstâncias o problema se manifesta e como replicar o problema sempre que necessário, facilitando bastante o trabalho de investigação de suas causas e da sua correção (além de evidenciar-se a própria existência do problema, obviamente).

Colocar um MVCE na pergunta não é estritamente necessário. E realmente tem pouco valor depois que a resposta é descoberta. Mas, em muitas perguntas, fazer-se isso facilita bastante a obtenção de respostas. E novamente friso que embora um esforço em relação ao **M** seja necessário, a maior parte das perguntas que têm problemas em relação ao MCVE pecam mais nas partes do **C** e do **V**, sendo passíveis de fechamento como "*não está clara o suficiente*" ou como "*este é um problema que não pode ser reproduzido*".

Comment: Obrigado pelo bom senso.