# Vale a pena ter perguntas/respostas canônicas para conteúdo off-topic?

Tags: debate, fechamento, qualidade

Andei pensando se não seria interessante criarmos algumas perguntas e respostas "sintéticas" (no sentido de artificialmente construídas) para usar como alvo de fechamento como duplicata de perguntas ruins que aparecem diariamente aqui.

A ideia seria dar instruções bem gerais para que as pessoas consigam resolver sozinhas problemas postados como "está dando erro, segue código ou link". Por exemplo, uma boa explicação sobre *rubber duck debugging*, acompanhada de links como o do artigo do Lippert, funcionaria para esse tipo de pergunta. Mas tem outros tipos, como as que dizem "como converter este código da linguagem X para Y" (para as quais a resposta curta é "aprenda as duas linguagens"), e outros com que andei esbarrando por aí.

Mas eu mesmo tenho dúvidas se isso é uma boa ideia, por isso trouxe pra cá. Se por um lado isso pode ajudar os usuários mais "sem noção" – especialmente os que têm dificuldades em formular perguntas adequadamente –, por outro lado tem potencial para aumentar a quantidade de conteúdo ruim no site – já que duplicatas não são excluídas automaticamente pelo sistema.

Tenho alguma esperança de que a existência dos conteúdos canônicos e o fechamento constante de dúvidas apontando para eles reduza o surgimento de conteúdos ruins no futuro, mas não temos como saber o que aconteceria sem testar. Por isso estendo a discussão a vocês: o que acham?

Comment: Eu tenho repensado se vale a pena fechar como duplicata quando a pergunta é ruim demais, ela não servirá nem pra SEO e apontar para algo já respondido. Se é *off off* eu acho que não deveria estar no site. Acho muito mais plausível ter perguntas *on* porém *off* mas a comunidade não gostou muito  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7855/101. Uma boa pergunta *on* é claro que pode, inclusive me parece que já tem uma do pato de borracha. Tem umas que servem assim, como a do Null (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/101)

Comment: Não era melhor ter essas perguntas no meta e linkar para aqui nos comentários?

Comment: ... e estou querendo terminar a minha de *out of bound* (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101), deveria ter mais dessas. Algumas questões apontadas eu acho que cabe algo no meta, ainda que já tem algo (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/101). Reduzir conteúdo ruim não, hoje mesmo aparece uma atrás da outras sobre *timezone* porque a infra da pessoa está errada e ela acha que é programação, e ela não procura. O que pode fazer é dar alguma orientação pra quem tem um pouco de vontade e noção, quem é muito sem noção ou falta total de vontade não tem o que fazer.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não acho o meta o lugar mais adequado, minha intenção era ter a resposta mais "na cara" das pessoas.

Comment: @Maniero mas essa é on-topic, o que está sendo proposto é para off-topic.

Comment: @Bacco estou reforçando o que eu acho válido.

Comment: Acho que perguntas *off-topic* tem mais é que fechar. No máximo escrever um comentário, seja dando uma dica, seja com um link para o [Manual de como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/112052) e/ou para o [artigo do Eric Lippert traduzido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/112052). O ideal mesmo é que a [interface do site orientasse melhor](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7892/112052) para minimizar a quantidade de perguntas ruins, mas enquanto nada disso é feito, ficamos aqui enxugando gelo...

Comment: @hkotsubo atualmente enxugando gelo com Cotonete®, dada a proporção de conteúdo aproveitável como repositório de conhecimento em relação ao resto.

Comment: Não tem muito a ver com a questão levantada aqui, mas acho que o "Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável" é muito subjetivo e abre muitas brechas. Fica difícil, para nós leigos, interpretá-lo. Vocês não acham que ele deveria ser revisado para se tornar mais objetivo ? Acho que falta até um pouco de coerência nos argumentos dos mais experientes, quando fecham uma pergunta, em relação ao "Exemplo mínimo". É só minha opinião de leigo. Talvez o problema realmente esteja nas nossas perguntas, enfim...

Comment: ... tanto que acontece de vocês fecharem a pergunta, mas mesmo assim tiveram usuários que responderam a pergunta de boas. Não me refiro no caso de duplicata.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento, O [mcve] é uma forma de triar perguntas do tipo "faça para mim" onde o usuário, em geral, não se deu ao trabalho de tentar resolver o problema. Geralmente essas perguntas já conhecidas de apostilas ou são exercícios de sala de aula que frequentemente são repetidas. Ou então são perguntas superficiais que geram inúmeros cenários de resolução e por mais que se apresentem soluções nenhuma satisfaz a resposta e um exemplo faria a poda nesses cenários. Outra utilidade do [mcve] é a possibilidade de orientar o AP diretamente sobre o código.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento de uma lida [Uso obrigatório do MCVE?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6600/uso-obrigat%c3%b3rio-do-mcve) e [Quantas possibilidade eu tenho de recuperar e melhorar a qualidade de minhas perguntas ja passadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7002/quantas-possibilidade-eu-tenho-de-recuperar-e-melhorar-a-qualidade-de-minhas-per/7005#7005)

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento Discordo, mas como vc mesmo disse, é um assunto diferente do que está sendo discutido aqui. Então se quiser discutir com mais profundidade sugiro que [faça outra pergunta aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (não esquecendo de pesquisar antes se já não foi discutido, claro). Só queria adiantar que o fato de alguém responder uma pergunta fora do escopo não faz com que a pergunta automaticamente passe a ser dentro do escopo, então vc já parte de uma premissa errada. Ter respostas não impede a pergunta de ser fechada.

Comment: Entendi. Eu sei que estou errado, hkotsubo. Só comentei aqui pra não ter que abrir uma pergunta só pra isso. E percebi também que aqui estavam reunidos a galera mais experiente. Vou pesquisar mais sobre isso. Só acho que a galera com mais experiência deveria ser um pouco mais maleável. Afinal, nós iniciantes, não fazemos por maldade. É tudo no intuito de aprender.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento mas justamente, o pessoal experiente não faz por maldade, é no intuito de melhorar o material que vai ensinar visitantes. O site não foi feito pensando em ensinar cada um em sua própria postagem, e sim produzir perguntas com problemas bem definidos que sirvam para uma quantidade grande de usuários (a mesma pergunta se aplicar para uma gama significativa de futuros visitantes, de maneira que as pessoas consigam achar o problema, vejam que é a mesma situação, e encontrem a soluçã9 - idealmente quem está chegando é que tem que ser maleável e aprender a usar o site